# Visual Basic 2008 Check if label is inside a panel

Tags: vb.net

So i've been trying to make a game with arrow keys. 
The label is the character, if the label is inside the object, it will do something...

But i got a very hard problem i cannot find on the internet.

How do i check if a label is inside of an object? Example: Picture box, and Panel.

I've tried this one.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Label1.Location.X = Panel1.Location.X And Label1.Location.Y = Panel1.Location.Y Then
        Me.Close() 'Any code.
    End If
End Sub
```

Doesn't work, 
any help would be appreciated.

I am a beginner by the way, i only make simple applications. Like escape the room, maze... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the label's parent property to see if it is inside the panel.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Label1.Parent IsNot Nothing AndAlso Label1.Parent Is Panel1 Then
        Me.Close() 'Any code.
   End If
End Sub
```

If you are looking to see if the Label is over the Panel I would try something like this. The ClientRectangle property is the rectangle the control takes up.  I am assuming the panel is bigger than the Label.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If  Panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(Label1.ClientRectangle) Then
        Me.Close() 'Any code.
    End If
End Sub
```

If it is smaller you can check if a point is in the Panel's rectangle.  For example top left corner

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If  Panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(new Point(Label1.Left, Label1.Top)) Then
        Me.Close() 'Any code.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So the third one works but only if the panel is very big... If its small it does not work.